# Postgres unsigned integer primary key maximum

Tags: postgresql

Postgres integer range is from -2147483648 to +2147483647. In mysql as i know you can use unsigned integer as primary key and get twice values for pk when it starts from 1 (`2147483647*2`).

I'm not sure is there a way to increase postgres integer range pk sequence from 2147483647 to `2147483647*2` if i don't need negative values? Can i just change maximum to 2147483647*2?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres doesn't have unsinged int. For a primary key with more than 2147483647, consider using `bigserial`.

Comment: so i can't set maximum to 2147483647*2?

Comment: @ZiiMakc: only if you use a `bigint`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set a large number for MAXIMUM and Postgresql will use the relevant numeric type for the counter. Here is an example:

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE the_long_road 
    MINVALUE 1 
    MAXVALUE 123456789012345
    START WITH 123456789000000;
-- try it several times
SELECT nextval('the_long_road');
```

Comment: but then i will need to use bigint as i understand?

Comment: Yes you will. It's a very small price to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you really want an integer you **can** get the range of values you want. You just have the keep in mind that the only purpose of a generated key is making *the row unique in the table - nothing else*. In that view negative values work perfectly well. So

```
create sequence long_wrap_seq as integer
       minvalue -2147483648  
       maxvalue +2147483647 
       start with 1 
       cycle;
     
create table long_wrap_seq(id integer default nextval('long_wrap_seq')
                  , ...
                  );
```

You now have a the sequence range 2147483647*2 (actually +1).